# Codecademy Battleships Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make my own version of codecademy's Battleships.

Here's my code so far.`

```
board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)


ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)



running = True
while running:
    print_board(board)
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:")) - 1 #-1 in order to make rows numbered from 1 to 5 for the user
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:")) - 1 #-1 in order to make cols numbered from 1 to 5 for the user



    if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
        print "Error: index out of bounds"

    elif guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sank my battleship!"
        running = False
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!"
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"`
```

The program works fine. I just have the idea of making multiple ships that have various lengths, and have two different boards so that two players can play and guess each other's ships. But let's do one thing at a time.

If I want to have multiple ships of say length 2 or 3, what would be a good strategy to represent these ships? My idea is to use a list representing the coordinates that the ship takes up on the grid, but each point has an x and a y coordinate. So would a ship of length three be a list with length three, made up of 3 lists of length 2, each with an x and y coordinate? This is where I get confused.

Answer (score 0):

In battleship, each player has two boards: one to put his ships on, the other to keep track of shots on the enemy.

To store the ships, you could just put a code number into an integer grid:

```
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 3 3 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```